# How do I gain access to the methods in a class when using Robot Framework?

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and building tests. I am having issues accessing the class methods inside my python file. I receive this error message

```
==============================================================================
Test temperature setpoint change response                             | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'setpoint_change' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From what I understand from the documentation this should work

**Robot File**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Integration


*** Keywords ***
Confirm Temperature Setpoint Can Be Changed
    setpoint_change



*** Test Cases ***
Test temperature setpoint change response
    Confirm Temperature Setpoint Can Be Changed
```

**Python File** Integration.py

```
class Integration(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def setpoint_change(self):
        print('stuff is happening..')
```

if I use this in the context of a static function it will work so that tells me my paths are correct and the logic is there, but something is going wrong with accessing from within a class.

From what I see this should work, it's mentioned in the documentation that if the filename is the same as the class name a simple Integration in my case would suffice - I have tried it both ways as in (Integration.Integration file and class name) along with just ( Integration ) and was not able to successfully access the class methods.

From other examples I see which are much older, there is the use of a keyword decorator that's accessible using robot.api import keyword which I have yet to see implemented in a modern post, kindly let me know where I'm going wrong here, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I have copy-pasted your files, `Integration.py` and the robot suite are in the same folder.
It works perfectly without any modifications. What version of Robot Framework do you use? Are there any other error message for you? Library import happens alright?

Comment: Your code works for me, too,. Are you certain you aren't getting import errors?

Comment: No, I meant an import error when robot tries to import the Integration library. If robot can't import a library, one of the natural side effects is that it won't be able to find any keywords in that library.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found it. So silly..

```
*** Settings ***

Library  Integration.py

*** Keywords ***
Confirm Temperature Setpoint Can Be Changed
    setpoint_change

*** Test Cases ***

 Test temperature setpoint change response
    Confirm Temperature Setpoint Can Be Changed
```

For the next person.. please be sure and pay extra attention to the spacing scheme Also I had to include the file extension type (.py) which I really thought I did not, it now can import my class and do it's thing and have access to the methods and what not within the python class that's defined

Comment: In case you didn't realize it, you can call the keyword like `Setpoint change`. You don't have to use the literal name of the method.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "pay extra attention to the spacing scheme". What spacing did you have to change?

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you. So what I meant by spacing is it's very senstive it seems, robot didnt like how I had so many spaces between test cases and keywords

Comment: I also have another question directly in-line with this.. does Robot actually instantiate the class thus the constructor gets invoked ? I am assuming yes ?

Comment: @TravHola Yes, the constructor gets called. You can even have and pass parameters.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries

Comment: Robot doesn't care how many spaces or blank lines you have between keywords and test cases.

Comment: I will once the timer let's me