# How to include a python class method as a keyword in the Robot Framework using Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am trying to import a method from the python class `ExampleLibrary` from the Python file `Example.py`
#Example.py

```
class ExampleLibrary:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    counter = 0

    def county(self):
        self.counter = 29
        print(self.counter)
        return self.counter

    def clear_counter(self):
        self.counter = 0
        print(self.counter)
```

My Robot file is like

```
*** Settings ***
Library     ExampleLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
This is a Sample Test
    [Documentation]  First Test
    [Tags]  Variables display
    ${var}   county
    log  ${var}
```

The robot framework is unable to recognize the keyword `county` from the `Example.py` but the `ExampleLibrary` class is being imported properly. I am using the Pycharm IDE. Can anyone help me out?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I gain access to the methods in a class when using Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63877031/how-do-i-gain-access-to-the-methods-in-a-class-when-using-robot-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code, and adding Example.py's location into the PYTHONPATH, I get two errors. These errors should be visible on the console and in the log.html as well and I think you should have both as well.

[image]

> Importing test library 'ExampleLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ExampleLibrary'

and

> No keyword with name 'county' found.

The second one is the consequence of the first one, and the problem is that there is no information where `ExampleLibrary` class is. To resolve this, and correctly import the library you should define in the robot file where the `ExampleLibrary` class can be found.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Example.ExampleLibrary
```

Your other choice could be to rename Example.py to ExampleLibrary.py. But if you have more classes in a Python file like in this question, [Inner nested class access from robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57660169/3820025), you could face similar problems.